# JavaScript added as link/stylesheet

Tags: css, javascript, wp-dependencies

I am just trying to create a plugin that will add some JS to the header and custom CSs. I have this below but it adds the css wrong and shows as JS. This is first plugin i have attempted.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: mmoore5553 Simple Range Slider
 * Plugin URI: mailto:mmoore5553@gmail.com
 * Description: Simple Range Slider
 * Version:  1.0
 * Author: mmoore5553@gmail.com
 * Author URI: 
 * License:GPL2
 */


function SimpleRangeSlider() {
wp_register_script('SimpleRangeSlider', plugins_url('/js/simple-slider.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('SimpleRangeSlider');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'SimpleRangeSlider' ); 



function SimpleRangeSlider1() {
wp_register_script('stylesheet1', plugins_url('/css/simple-slider.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('stylesheet1');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'SimpleRangeSlider1' );  

function SimpleRangeSlider2() {
wp_register_script('stylesheet2', plugins_url('/css/simple-slider-volume.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('stylesheet2');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'SimpleRangeSlider2' );  
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script` is for… scripts. You want [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) (and [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)) for stylesheets.

Also note that you can enqueue as many things as you'd like in a single function, no need to create a separate function for each. You can also pass all the same arguments to enqueue as you do to register, no need to register them first if you're just enqueueing in one place.

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it working. I did not know you could put it all in one. Thank you on the correct syntax. I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

As Milo already told you, you need to use wp_enqueue_script for scripts and use wp_enqueue_style for Stylesheet files.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Read these pages, they will give all the info you need.

Also, you can actually enqueue multiple scripts / styles in single function, no need to create function for each style file or script file enqueue.

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.